# Change CSS class depending on URL in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, menu

I am trying to make a menu that I could use on all pages on a site using XSLT.

I have an XSL:

```
<xsl:template match="header/menu">
  <div class="header__menu">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="item"/> 
  </div>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="menu/item">
  <div class="header__menu-item">
    <a class="link">
        <xsl:attribute name="href">
            <xsl:value-of select="../item/@url"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
     </a>
  </div>
</xsl:template>
```

XML:

```
 <header>
    <menu>
      <item url="#">Work</item>
      <item url="#">About</item>
      <item url="#">Blog</item>
    </menu>
 </header>
```

I would like to change CSS class of a menu item depending on the page (active class when the page is opened and no link).

I thought about trying xsl:choose construction and check for the page URL, but don't have an idea how to do that.

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: XSLT on its own won't have any knowledge of the page URL, so you will have to pass the current URL as a parameter? How are you currently calling the XSLT to perform the transformation? (For example, in PHP, ASP.Net, JavaScript, etc?).

Comment: I currently use php. I have an index.php file in the directory which calls an xsl (which imports header.xsl and other) and an xml for the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although there may be extension methods you can use in XSLT to get the URL, it might be easier for you to pass the URL to the XSLT as a parameter via PHP. See this documentation for example: http://docs.php.net/manual/en/xsltprocessor.setparameter.php

In your XSLT itself, you would then have a parameter defined like so

```
<xsl:param name="url" />
```

In terms of using it, you could use an **xsl:choose**, so your XSLT could look something like this (In this case I am putting the css class on the **a** tag, but it could easily go on the containing **div** tag if you wanted.

```
<xsl:template match="menu/item">
  <div class="header__menu-item">
    <a class="link" href="{@url}">
     <xsl:attribute name="class">
        <xsl:choose>
           <xsl:when test="$url = @url">active</xsl:when>
           <xsl:otherwise>inactive</xsl:when>
        <xsl:choose>
      </xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </a>
  </div>
</xsl:template>
```

As an aside, do note the use of "Attribute Value Templates" in creating your existing **href** attribute. The curly braces `{ }` indicate an expression to be evaluated, not output literally.

Comment: Thanks Tim C. I just haven't yet figured out completely how to pass the url into xsl parameter.

Comment: Got an answer about passing the URL in PHP if anyone might need that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25826220/pass-url-as-a-parameter-to-xsl